# Replacing com.google.inject with javax.inject

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

Is it true that javax.inject annotations can function as direct replacements for com.google.inject?

So that, if I replaced all my current guice/gin annotations with those from javax.inject, my app would compile and run just fine?

First, does javax.inject cover all the bases that google.inject cover?

Comment: Please don't edit my guice tag away.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, it will work fine. In fact the author of guice (Bob Lee) is a spec-lead for the `javax.inject` specification.

`javax.inject.Inject` does not have the `optional` attribute, so if you want an optional dependency, you'd have to use the guice annotation.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, I have chosen to refrain from switching to javax.inject, because I find the spec much minimalistic in comparison to what Guice provides (which I use):

- `@Optional` as mentioned by @Bozho
- `@ImplementedBy` which is very useful when you want to reduce the number of explicit bindings (for code clarity) and when you want to be able to easily override the default `@ImplementedBy` binding if you need (e.g. for integration tests).

There are probably others but for me these 2 are showstoppers already.

Answer (score 7):

See [JSR-330 Integration on Guice's site](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JSR330).